# Leave paper.js path as uninteractable pixels in background

Tags: paperjs

I have a little program in which a function is slowly painting the background with little random dots. Only problem is that early on in the animation there are so many symbol objects representing these dots that it starts to lag. I have made it as light as possible by having all symbols be based on the same circle path. When I instead use new paths instead of basing every circle on the same path the lag starts much earlier.

From using regular js canvas, I remember that when one had drawn a shape it would remain there and not bother the system anymore, right? I have tried putting a separate canvas behind (with absolute positioning), but am having troubles with resizing. I think the paper.js initialization screws with the scale of both canvases.

Is it possible somehow to, as with regular canvas JS, draw the path, then let the canvas forget about it and leave it in the background?
If not, does anyone have an idea for a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Group` to contain all of the dots you want to generate. After each frame, rasterize the group along with the previous frame, then call `group.remove()`. For example:

```
var raster = new Raster();

function onFrame(event){
    var raster2;
    var group = new Group();

    // add the previous frame
    group.appendBottom(raster);

    var path;
    for(i = 0; i < 70; i++){
        path = new Path.Circle({
            center: view.size * Point.random(),
            radius: 20,
            fillColor: new Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())
        });
        group.appendTop(path);
    }
    raster2 = group.rasterize();
    group.remove();
    raster = raster2;
}
```

[Here it is on sketch.paperjs.org.](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/lVJNb4MwDP0rEaewVqjqZRKsl1XaTpOqbbexQwZmjQp2ZAKVVvHfl/BROm7zIfGL7fdiJ5cAVQVBHLydwGbHYB1klHvcKhasagssdgLhLF57IMMkxRSLBjOrCQXhEzsCCS2gDS8pCmdz7TaZT76ZGjOSPXu/5/LRPhIpYwDzR7KWKjmUhzflRtnjCAtiqXebRD/cu2W1mnS9+bRR5ODcaK85K0HeZHjL3G2BY9FqOEe1/gFxJw6k0UasMHf64fpvAatcN3UstptFoNBluaeSHJnX7F354pWvTOIfMJzZu6n75YjeyUjf5hTvhm2cuGt+SB6w620xZ4aK2vnw+sjzi3XuG3wxqJPxI6mD+OOz+wU=)

Comment: Perfect! I had the idea previously to rasterize, but didn't know I could append a raster and re-rasterize it with paths. Thanks!